# How to Quickly Extract Rows from Pandas DataFrame, Based on Column Values that Reference Column Indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a pandas dataframe of points made up of measures (trying to simplify the problem here: a point is a latitude/longitude position on a planet, a measure is an instantiation of that on an image so has pixel x/y values).  I have a column for point_id and a column for serialnumber (of the image).  I also have a column called referenceIndex.  The reference index refers to the image, within a given point, that was used as the reference against which other images are compared.  Here's an example of how that might be set up, simplifying column names and cell values:

```
   PtID  SN  RI
0   A    a   0
1   A    b   0
2   A    c   0
3   B    b   1
4   B    d   1
5   C    a   1
6   C    e   1
```

In the example, I have 3 points.  Point A exists on 3 images (a,b,c), and the reference image was a.  Point B exists on 2 images, and the reference image was d (because reference index = 1).  Point C exists on 2 images, and the reference image is e.

An input is a CSV of point_id,serialnumber to extract.  That list *might not* have the reference measure in the list and is not something I can modify.  And, if it doesn't, I need some way to preserve it.

```
Example Input:  {A,a}
Example Output: row: {0}

Example Input:  {C,a}
Example Output: row: {5,6}
```

The first example is easy.  The second one is harder: My input list only wanted row 5, but to preserve that reference measure for point_id C, I also have to extract row 6.

Help?

---

---

P.S.  This is the code I came up with.  The else: statement is many times slower than my original method (where the original method doesn't do what I want.

```
if args.flagKEEPREF == "false":
    newDF_idx =[]
    for measure in arr_measures:
        test = (df.loc[(df.point_id == measure[0]) & (df.serialnumber == measure[1])]).index
        if len(test) > 0:           #account for case where the measure does not exist in the network
            newDF_idx.append(test[0])
    df = df.iloc[list(set(newDF_idx))]
    df.sort_values(by=['point_id', 'serialnumber'])
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
else:
    gb = [x for _, x in df.groupby('point_id')] #create groups based on point_id
    newDF_idx = []
    for group in gb:
        referenceIndex = group.iloc[0]['referenceIndex']
        for measure in arr_measures:
            if measure[0] in group['point_id'].values:  #optimization: can pre-screen
                test = (group.loc[(group.point_id == measure[0]) & (group.serialnumber == measure[1])]).index
                if len(test) > 0:                       #account for case where the measure does not exist in the network
                    newDF_idx.append(test[0])
                    newDF_idx.append(group.index[referenceIndex]) #use the index within the group to get the index in the original array
    df = df.iloc[list(set(newDF_idx))]
    df.sort_values(by=['point_id', 'serialnumber'])
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This is a lot of text and code to read through. From my experience the best way to get answers is to include and example dataframe (which you already have) then some short explanation, finally an expected output, so people can visually see what you want to do

Comment: I'll edit to shorten.

Comment: It's shorter now, I separated the example code I'm working from, and I added an example in/out of what works vs what is harder.